# .net IE8 hash url redirect

Tags: asp.net

the scenario is, my users are redirected to a login page when they are not logged in. and the page they're trying to hit has a hash fragment with the URL (myPage.aspx#abc).

i'm using .net 4.0 web form Response.Redirect to redirect. and i know that the server side does not get anything after the hash fragment  so i can't redirect on the server side unless i do a hidden field and i don't want to do that if there's another option.

i looked at a solution in this post 
[ASP.NET postbacks lose the hash in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885568/asp-net-postbacks-lose-the-hash-in-the-url)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    document.getElementById("aspnetForm").action += location.hash
});
```

it works in firefox/chrome but not IE8. by the time the comes back form the server, location.hash is already "" in IE8.

any thoughts? is there another event i should be attached that too?

thanks!

Comment: Does the hash change per user or is it static?  If it's static you could just do a `Response.Redirect` with the hash, otherwise you could pull user specific data after they authenticate and add that to the redirect.  Would that work?

Comment: the hash is dynamic and is not specific to each user. so either won't work.

Comment: What about setting the value in a session variable before redirecting them to the login page?  Then re-apply it on the button click event of the login form.

Comment: there's no way to get the hash value on the server side

Comment: How are you initially placing the hash on the URL?  If it's done in code, you could save the session then.